# How to display query error in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli query that wont execute and I would like to display information about why that's happening. Im just fooling around with this example but I imagine something like this:

```
$myQuery= $mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET id = 1 WHERE id = 3");
if(!$myQuery) //If query couldnt be executed
{
echo $mysqli->error; //Display information about why wasnt executed (eg. Error: couldnt find table)
}
```

Comment: please check you requirement for updating the records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using

```
// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET id = 1 WHERE id = 3"))
{
 echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```